# Does everyone shares the same javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, database

So I'm using Javascript and ajax to connect to a database through an php file, but something came in mind.

If a User log in, the user data will be stored in my Javascript file tittle `UserProces.js` as:

```
Var Username = "James"
Var Age ="25";
```

(Data obtain from a query through a php: `RetrieveUserData.php`)

If 1 minute after James loged in, another user name Amy log in will the values of name and age of amy will effect the values of James? Since there is only one `UserProces.js`.

Comment: Hmmm... JavaScript file is not a database. Which you actually have, a JS file or a database?

Comment: No no no.. Javascript is used **CLIENT SIDE** only. That means changing javascript values would not reflect changes on other browser. You must save it on server side eg. database, file etc. .

Comment: @BhaveshGangani You _can_ store variables in a JS _file_, usually not very practical though.

Comment: @Teemu  yes we can store variables in JS file. But changes on one client doesn't reflect changes in other's browser.

Comment: @BhaveshGangani OP says: "through an php file", which makes it possible to manipulate a JS file at a server.

Comment: Yes we can. But its not practical and convient way to do it.

Comment: **This** is the reason why you need to seperate business logic, configuration and view/markup.

Comment: Yes, Amy definitely will override the previous values. You'd need a real database (MySql or something similar), or an own JS file for every user.

Comment: This is the most botched question I've seen on SO. Javascript files are downloaded to the browser and run locally. They are not written to, the are executed in memory. Another user in cyberspace will not see what anyone else is doing. Think of it like a form. If you are filling out a form will someone else that goes to the site see what you are filling out? Of course not. The question, and several of the comments, demonstrate a fundamental lack of understanding of how the web and browsers work.

Comment: @Crowcoder Again: "... connect to a database through an php file ... the user data will be stored in my javascript file ..." Is it that hard to understand, that you can write a JS file to a server using PHP? There will be only one file, which _all_ users will load to and execute in their machines ...

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question, there seems to be different opinions here about what are you actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Of course NO! Each user is getting his local copy of  javascript file.

Comment: Ehh... if it's a _copy_, aren't all users sharing the same _file_?

Comment: No, they don't share.

Answer (score 0):

The server sends each client that requests the page a copy of the javascript file it has stored. That copy is then in their browser and running there. Any changes to variables are done in that copy in their browser. They have to way (well, unless you set up something special) to change the original file on the server. Think of it like this:

I'm a teacher with a test document on my computer (this is the javascript file on the server). For each student who comes into the class and asks to take the test (a client requesting the page) I'm going to print off a copy in my printer and give them. They will then write their name on the test and fill in answers (assign values to variables). A student doing this doesn't effect anyone else in the class because they aren't changing the original document, they are just editing their copy.

Not a perfect analogy, obviously, but pretty darn close.

Also, addressing a comment made earlier, you probably aren't accessing the service "through a php file". You are using a php file to generate a copy of the web page for the user to view. Again, printing off a copy for the user, but in this case the php file gives a special set of instructions for exactly what should be "printed off".

Answer (score 0):

Each user will load the same script file but all variables, objects and everything else gets stored by each browser, and even your browser doesnt share that info, which prevents one website to have access to variables on another website.

So, final answer is no. They will not share any info. Just load the same "base".